# angularjs ng-repeat doesn't populate value for the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Not sure if this question is already answered, but couldn't find anything on google.

Couldn't get `myDirective` to get `item-data` correctly, It always gets `item.Data` as the value.

```
<div class="items" ng-repeat="item in Items">
<div class="itemInclude">
    <div class="item-body">
        <h4 class="text-center">{{item.name}}</h4>
        <myDirective item-data="{{item.Data}}"></myDirective>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the directive

```
angular.module('item', [])
.directive('itemDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: require('item-list.html'),
        link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.Items = [
        {
          "name": item1,
          "data": item1Data
        },
        {
          "name": item2,
          "data": item2Data
        },
        {
          "name": item3,
          "data": item3Data
        },
        {
          "name": item4,
          "data": item4Data
        }
        ]
        //some stuff
        }
  };
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your directive code?

Comment: Where is directive code?

Comment: Try without the double-curly braces for your attribute.

Comment: Do you add your directive on script for your html page ?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, it didn't work. @ MohamedYakout, Yes.

Comment: try using ng-transclude on the other directive.

Comment: I'm confused why your directive is trying to define your items[].  I usually put that kind of stuff inside a controller.  Does item.name appear properly?

Comment: @ryanyuyu It is inside link function.

Comment: Um, just a quick check, your items[] is defined strangely.  Javascript objects don't have quotes around the property names.  And if those properties are strings, then they need the quotes.  See if this helps with the ng-repeat (probably won't for the directive) http://plnkr.co/edit/2YsssWoQq53viB1YW8Vi

Comment: THis is very confusing. THe directive here is called itemDirective, not myDirective. The ng-repeat is referencing something insdie itemDirective. Are there nested directives here? We need to see the entire code to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rename the variables so a distinction is more clear. You are for instance referencing item.Data instead of item.data (your mistake?). Easy to make a mistake. Rename your directive items like itemDir or something.